# Interact with SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, vbscript

I'm writing a VBS program which interact with a SQLite database.

This database contains 2 tables: `Follow` and `Unfollow`.

In the `Follow` table I have 2 columns : `Name` and `Joined`.
`Name` is the name of an account and `Joined` is the date when I followed this account.

In the `Unfollow` table I have 1 column: `Name`.
`Name` is the name of an account that I unfollow.

My code:

```vb
Dim objConn, objRecordSet, following, search_value, search_value2, search_value3

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Connexion database SQLite
objConn.Open("DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Users\Quentin\Downloads\Quentin-Classementhashtags.db")

following = "toto"

'Query to look if a recording exists
objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Follow WHERE Name = '" & following & "';", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'Travels the database to know if the following already exists
If (objRecordSet.EOF) Then
    search_value = 0
Else
    search_value = 1
End If

objRecordSet.Close

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Unfollow WHERE Name = '" & following & "';", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If (objRecordSet.EOF) Then
    search_value2 = 0
Else
    search_value2 = 1
End If

objRecordSet.Close

'Query to look for the recordings which date more than 20 days
objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Follow WHERE Joined < datetime(CURRENT_DATE, '-20 days');", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If (objRecordSet.EOF) Then
    search_value3 = 0
Else
    search_value3 = 1
End If

objRecordSet.Close

'Insert into the table Follow a new line containing the following last one if it does not already exist
If search_value = 0 Then
    objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Follow (Name, Joined) VALUES ('" & following & "', CURRENT_DATE);", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End If

'Insert into the table Unfollow a new line containing the following if it does not already exist and what it dates more than 20 days
If search_value2 = 0 And search_value3 = 1 Then
    objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Unfollow (Name) VALUES ('" & following & "');", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End If

objConn.Close
```

My code works when I want to add a follow in my `Follow` table. But this didn't work for the second part:

```vb
If search_value2 = 0 And search_value3 = 1 Then
    objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Unfollow (Name) VALUES ('" & following & "');", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End If
```

If the record already exists in the `Unfollow` table, that doesn't write it, but no matter if it dates more than 20 days or not, that always writes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM Follow
WHERE Joined < datetime(CURRENT_DATE, '-20 days')
```

returns *all* names from `Follow` that date back more than 20 days, meaning you'll insert the given name into `Nofollow` if there is *any* record in `Follow` dating back that far, not just the record with that particular name.

What you actually want is something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Nofollow
SELECT Name
FROM Follow t1
WHERE t1.Name = 'foo'
  AND t1.Joined < datetime(CURRENT_DATE, '-20 days')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Nofollow t2 WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name)
```

That will insert the given name into `Nofollow` only if it is present in `Follow` with a date more than 20 days ago.

However, you want to avoid building the query via string concatenation in your VBScript, i.e. do ***NOT*** do something like this:

```vb
"INSERT INTO Nofollow " & _
"SELECT Name FROM Follow t1 " & _
"WHERE t1.Name='" & name & "' AND ..."
'              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ evil!
```

because that would make you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead use a [parameterized query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200190) (AKA prepared statement):

```vb
name = "foo"
qry  = "INSERT INTO Nofollow " & _
       "SELECT Name FROM Follow t1 " & _
       "WHERE t1.Name=? AND t1.Joined < datetime(CURRENT_DATE, '-20 days') " & _
       "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Nofollow t2 WHERE t2.Name=t1.Name)"

db = "C:\path\to\your.db"
cs = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & db

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open cs

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = qry

Set p = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", 200, 1, 255, name)
cmd.Parameters.Append p

cmd.Execute

cn.Close
```

If you want to insert all names dating back more than 20 days that aren't already present in the table `Nofollow` you need a slightly different query without the parameter for a name:

```vb
qry  = "INSERT INTO Nofollow " & _
       "SELECT Name FROM Follow t1 " & _
       "WHERE t1.Joined < datetime(CURRENT_DATE, '-20 days') " & _
       "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Nofollow t2 WHERE t2.Name=t1.Name)"

db = "C:\path\to\your.db"
cs = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & db

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open cs

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = qry

cmd.Execute

cn.Close
```

Comment: Ok Thanks Ansgar, and if I want to add all records that date more than 20 days, not just my following ?

Comment: I want to execute 2 queries in the same VBS program but I gett an error.

Comment: I found a solution.